# Comparing two values from two different tables using nested foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table of item and a table cart. What I'm trying to do is fetch all instances of item and cart then I put them in the loop such that whenever the item's item_id matches the cart's item_id,  I'll subtract cart's item_quantity value from item's number_of_units. The result is then used to update item's number_of_items. There's seems to be a problem with my nested foreach loop.

Here's a function in my controller

```
public function checkout(){

    $this->load->model('HomeModel');
    $x['item'] = $this->HomeModel->displayAllItems();
    $y['cart'] = $this->HomeModel->displayAllCartItems();

    foreach($x['item'] as $item){
        foreach($y['cart'] as $cart){

            if(($item->item_id) == ($cart->item_id)){

                $temp1 = $item->number_of_units; 
                $temp2 = $cart->item_quantity;

                $temp = $temp1 - $temp2;

                $z = array(
                    'number_of_units' => $temp,
                );

                $this->HomeModel->updateItem($z, $item->item_id);
            }   
        }
    }

}
```

Here's some of my model functions:

```
public function displayAllCartItems()
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('cart')->get();
    return $query->result();
}

public function displayAllItems()
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('item')->get();
    return $query->result();
}

public function updateItem($data, $id)
{
    $this->db->where('item_name', $id);
    $query = $this->db->update('item', $data);
}
```

Comment: Why not just use SQL?

Comment: Why not just use $cart->item_id to directly act on the item table? If you're not familiar with the SQL Paul Andrew suggests just do something like `$temp = get_item($cart->item_id);` and reduce the quantity and then update it.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html#updating-the-cart why not use CI's own cart class

Comment: Thanks for the idea Pacio. I think I know what to do now. :)

Comment: Have you thought about having model functions that just return the item_ids (for both items and carts), then using PHP's in_array to do the comparison?

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion cfnerd! I finally resolved my problem by having just one foreach loop in the controller, I then call a model function inside the loop passing the item_ids and number_of_units and in the model function, I used another foreach loop to compare the passed item_ids with the cart_ids that I fetched using another function. :)